# The choice between answers in spoken English

Tags: phrase-choice, sentence-choice

If I'm speaking to somebody and I need to emphasize that what someone told me is true. What's my best option?

- **I assure you**, she told me the truth!
- **Trust me**, she told me the truth!
- **Believe me**, she told me the truth!
- **That's a hundred percent** she told me the truth!

Apart from those I've proposed are there any other good ways to say this?

Comment: Sometimes less is more. In the right tone, just *She told me the truth* could be a great choice. (Try to say it solemnly. It could add gravity to your word very effectively.)

Comment: I wish to emphasize the truth, not just state it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**God's honest truth**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/god-s-truth) can be used to emphasise something as being definitely true.

> What she told me, it's the God's honest truth!

If you have independently verified the fact, you could also say that, e.g.

> It's true, I checked!

Edit:

**Unequivocal** is also a good word to use.

> She told me the unequivocal truth.

Or

> It's unequivocally true.

Comment: What if I shorten the first to: What she told me is God's honest truth!

Comment: Yes that would be OK

Comment: They're probably still alive and kicking in *American* casual speech, but I think expressions like *It's God's honest truth* (and variations on a theme such as *I swear to God / by all that's holy / on my life it's true* all sound a bit *passé* to me.